# Facing 'MongoDB 5.0.6 2008R2Plus SSL (64 bit) setup wizard ended prematurely' error

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, windows-installer

These are the prompts i face whenever i try to install the msi file.I also tried installing it by unchecking mongodb compass but still facing the same error.
I also tried installing by zip file and version 4.4.12 but still facing some error
Firewall is Disable
Antivirus in off
temp Directory is clean
and windows installer service restarted

> the windows installer service could not be accessed, this can occur if you are running windows in safe mode, or if the windows installer is not correctly installed contact your support personnel for assistance mongodb win 10

[image]

Comment: Did you try to run the Setup from Admin account? When you unzip the .zip file you should not get the error. Maybe an MonogDB service is installed already, you need to stop (and maybe remove) it before.

Comment: tnx Wernfried 
i see my runing service in task manager . mongodb and similar services is not found

Comment: You need to check service manager `services.msc`, perhaps service is created but not started.

Comment: Did you try to install the service with the installer? I prefer to skip this option and create the service manually with `mongod.exe --config <your config file> --install`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes i did , but finally i use  .zip file tanks bro